# Django: is_valid() method is always return false when use with ModelForm

Tags: python, django, forms, modelform

is_valid() method is always returning false when i use forms.ModelForm in forms.py to create form,so that i can save all values getting from form which is input by user.This code works fine with forms.Form but not with forms.ModelForm

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import student

class student_data(forms.ModelForm):
    name=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput,max_length=20)
    id=forms.IntegerField()
    address=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput,max_length=50)

    class Meta():
        model=student
        fields=['name','stu_id','address']
```

here is models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class student(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    stu_id=models.IntegerField()
    address=models.CharField(max_length=60)

    class Meta:
        db_table='student'
```

here is views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import student
from .forms import student_data

def my_data(request):
    stu1_name=''
    stu2_name=''
    stu_name=''
    myform=student_data(request.POST)
    if (request.method=="POST" and myform.is_valid()):
        stu_name=myform.cleaned_data['name']
        stu1_name=myform.cleaned_data['id']
        stu2_name=myform.cleaned_data['address']
        myform.save()
    else:
        myform=student_data
    return render(request,'show.html',{'student':stu_name,'id':stu1_name,'address':stu2_name})
```

html file for form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form name="form" action="/payment/show/" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}
            <button type="submit">Add Me</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code as below and try

```
def my_data(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        myform = student_data(request.POST)
        if myform.is_valid():
            myform.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        myform = student_data()
    return render(request, '----.html', {'myform': myform})
```

Comment: thank you now my code is working but form is creating one more extra input tag named id why?now i get we need to redirect user if we want to work with modelform thank you man.